# Activating default route if no other carbon-route active

Tags: polymer, carbon-route

Since Polymer 1.4 carbon-route is available, which can be used for navigation:

```
<carbon-location
        route="{{route}}"
        use-hash-as-path>
</carbon-location>

<carbon-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/tabs/:tabName"
        data="{{data}}">
</carbon-route>
```

However, if none of the routes match when the page initially loads, then the URL is not updated when the route changes.

Is there a way to select a default route when no other route matches?

For example, in excess-route, this could be done via:

```
<excess-route
        route="/(.*)"
        redirect-to="/default"
        activation-modifiers="x">
</excess-route>
```

It looks like there's an open issue for this, is there a good work-around?
https://github.com/PolymerElements/carbon-route/issues/68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the new `fallback-selection` attribute on iron-selectables like `iron-pages` or `paper-tabs`: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-selector/blob/master/iron-selectable.html#L121

At time of writing this property is very new and isn't yet up on the elements guide. You may also need to do a bower update locally as well to get the new code.

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question, the following can be used as a work-around:

```
...

<carbon-location
        route="{{route}}"
        use-hash-as-path>
</carbon-location>

<carbon-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/tabs/:tabName"
        data="{{data}}">
</carbon-route>

<paper-tabs
        selected="{{data.tabName}}"
        attr-for-selected="key">
    <paper-tab key="foo">Foo</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab key="bar">Bar</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>

...

Polymer({
    ...

    properties: {
        data: {
            type: Object,
            observer: "_onData"
        }
    },

    _onData: function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (! newValue.tabName) {
            window.location = ("" + window.location).replace(/\#.*$/, "") + "#/tabs/foo";
        }
    }
});
```